# Extracting Map content in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I got this Map: `Map(term -> Buffer(hello), callback -> Buffer(jsonp1350647507240))` and I want to extract the values `hello` and `jsonp1350647507240` from it. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access just the values of a `Map` by calling `values`

From the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html): `def values: Iterable[B]`

I can only assume that `hello` and `jsonp135...0` are supposed to be strings, in which case you could just use `mkString` on the buffers.

The end result would be:

```
val myValues = myMap.values.map{ _.mkString }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the map and pattern match on the `(key, value)` elements:

```
map foreach {
  case (_, v) => println(v)
}
```

If you want to return something based on the values you could use `map` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `Map.values` method will return a `Iterable` of your values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `hello` and `jsonp....` are strings in the following case class:

```
case class Buffer(name: String)
```

You can write:

```
val list = myMap.map {
  case (key, buff) => buff.name
}
```

and you have a list object => `List(Hello, jsonp1350647507240)` which you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: or `case (key, Buffer(name)) => name`